# How to get a field value and all related elements by using that field value in the same query?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has these fields:

```
clickId, ip, date
```

I need to get all dates in which an user (with an IP like 192.168.0.55) did clicks, and for every date how many clicks he did.

How can I do this with one single MySql query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` along with an aggregation function.

```
SELECT date, COUNT(*) AS click_count
FROM YourTable
WHERE IP = '192.168.0.55'
GROUP BY date
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just group by the ip and date. if it is a datetime you need to group by DATE(date)

```
SELECT  ip, DATE(date), COUNT(*) as num_clicks
FROM your_table
GROUP BY ip, DATE(date)
```

this will be for all ip addresses by a specific date. you can also specify a specific ip address in a WHERE clause 
aka. `WHERE ip = "192.168.0.55"`

Comment: I would recommend using `DATE(date)` in both the select and group by statements. Otherwise, you might get some discrepancy.

Comment: @McAdam331 true, assuming its a datetime and not date :) i just added the DATE() part just incase its a datetime

Comment: Yeah, I knew where you were coming from. But it might be confusing when you GROUP BY '2014-12-22' and in your results get something like '2014-12-22 10:34:33'. Correct answer either way, though, since getting the number of clicks was the important part.